# (NodeJs, Express) including an EJS file with only functions results in error

Tags: node.js, function, express, include

I am currently setting up a shop with Node, and there are a lot of helper functions that I will re-use across different template files (such things as calc_taxes() ... ) For some odd reason, when I try to include a template partial that contains only functions, I get an error in the console.

(i'm using this syntax)

```
<%- include functions.ejs %>
```

**the error I'm getting**

```
express deprecated res.send(body, status): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead routes/errors.js:11:7
```

**example code**

```
 <% products.forEach(function(product){ %>

        <div class="item" dkit-grid="col-3">
            <div class="item_img" dkit-grid="col-12">
                <img src="<%= get_product_image( product ) %>">
            </div>

            <div class="item_desc" dkit-grid="col-12">
                <a href="/produit/<%= get_product_slug( product ) %>" class="item_name"> 
                    <%= get_product_name( product ) %> 
                </a>
                <span class="item_price"> 
                    <%= get_product_price( product ) %> 
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <% }); %>
```

I have tested with a file containing dummy content like an `<h1>wowow</h1>` and it outputted... But with my file containing only a bunch of function declaration I get nothing :(.

Comment: Do you have `routes/errors.js` and `res.send(arg11, arg2)` on line 11?

Answer (score 0):

After much trying I finally found a way to do this. If you are having the same error, or reference errors, first you need to add to your app.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

In your include call, make sure you use this syntax:

```
<%- include functions.ejs %>
```

When you declare your functions, make sure you do not use 'var' or 'let' because your functions will be stuck in the scope of that document, here is an example that works:

```
get_product_slug = function(product){
    return product.slug;
}
```

Voilà !